# Drawing Lines on a Canvas from a For-Loop in Typescript doesnt render

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop, canvas

I was making a graphing utility for fun, and then it turned into a real project...

I was trying to achieve a very simple graph... a line graph.

However, using a for-loop inside of my typescript project yields no results.

Look in the source code below, you can see I have console logs where I need to confirm an action is occuring. All of them run fine and in the perfect order in my typescript project.

Since SO doesnt support typescript, heres a codepen with the **full source and typescript compiler:** https://codepen.io/SkylerSpark/pen/zYvpWNZ

Snippet causing me the issues:

> g.px & g.py are my coordinates. They are grabbed from this array (its an example array of pizza sales):

```js
const pizzas = {
    x: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40],
    y: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    px: [0, 5.2, 7, 20.9, 34.3, 39.5],
    py: [0, 1.1, 1.3, 2.7, 3.5, 3.9]
};
```

```js
// Draw Numbers
if (g.px.length == g.py.length) {
    console.log("confirm");
    for (var i = 1; i < g.px.length + 1; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            console.log("start");
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(g.px[i], g.py[i]);
        } else if (i < g.px.length) {
            console.log("continue");
            ctx.lineTo(g.px[i], g.py[i]);
        } else {
            console.log("draw");
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Now see the picture below, its running fine:
[image]

Comment: The erased warnings in the console are codepen's Illegal Same-Site HTTP Cookies if anyone was curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your y-values need to be negative. In situations like these it's often useful to just draw any line instead of immediately using loops. I found this out by adding the following code

```js
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-40, -40);
        ctx.lineTo(40, -40);
        ctx.lineTo(40, 40);
        ctx.lineTo(-40, 40);
        ctx.stroke();
```

just before you start drawing the line, which actually shows some results. If I change `g.py[i]` to `-g.py[i]` everywhere, then a small line is added to the bottom left of the graph. Hope this helps!

[image: the result]

Comment: *facepalm* I completely forgot about the -y thing... I had been playing with negative and positive math all afternoon yesterday just to get those numbers to render correctly. Guess my brain got too mushy. Now that I know that, I can actually calculate the real positions of the x and y and draw em